# Is there a way of getting this string down to 3 words?

Tags: python

There are multiple problems with the code i posted below, since as i also said on my previous post im new to coding i have some trouble finding stuff by myself :(

My goal is to take user input, narrow it down to 3 words by size and then sort them alphabetically. Am i doing this right?

Probably not because it prints it out with commas. For example, with "i like eating cake" as input, the output is:

```
"'cake',", "'eating'", "'i',", "'like',"
```

But I want it to be:

```
cake, eating, like
```

Any help is much appreciated.

```
input = input(" ")
prohibited = {'this','although','and','as','because','but','even if','he','and','however','cosmos','an','a','is','what','question :','question','[',']',',','cosmo',' ','  ','   '}
processedinput = [word for word in re.split("\W+",input) if word.lower() not in prohibited]
processed = processedinput
processed.sort(key = len)
processed = re.sub('[\[\]]','',repr(processedinput)) #removes brackets
keywords = processed
keywords = keywords.split()
keywords.sort(key=str.lower)
keywords.sort()
keywords = re.sub('[\[\]]','',repr(keywords))
str(keywords)
print(keywords)
```

Comment: Thanks to everybody that helped me edit the question, much appreciated..

Comment: FYI, indentations caused the formatting issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue with your code is `input = input()`. The problem with this is that `input` is the name of the function you are calling, but you are overwriting `input` with the user's string. Consequently, if you tried to run `input()` again, it would fail.

The second issue is that you are misunderstanding lists. In the code below, `tokens` is a list, not a string. Each element in the list is a string. So there is no need to strip out brackets and such. You can simply order the list (that part of your code was correct) in *reverse* order of length, then print the first three words.

**Code:**

```
import re

user_input = input(" ")
prohibited = {'this','although','and','as','because','but','even if','he','and','however','cosmos','an','a','is','what','question :','question','[',']',',','cosmo',' ','  ','   '}
tokens = [word for word in re.split("\W+", user_input) if word.lower() not in prohibited]
tokens.sort(key=len, reverse=True)

print(tokens[0], end=', ')
print(tokens[1], end=', ')
print(tokens[2])
```

**Input:**

```
i like eating cake
```

**Output:**

```
eating, like, cake
```